# Integration of Two Variable Function?

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I was thinking about this concept, maybe I'm conceptually wrong can you all please go through this... http://blog.saikat.in/integration-two-variable

So far I have checked on 2-3 functions and it did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My honest opinion: I fail to see any new concept, I think you are just abusing notation. First you define $f'(x,y) = 3x^2+y$ and then you identify $f'(x,y) = dy/dx$. There is no two-variable function, you are just solving the ordinary differential equation $f'(x) = 3x^2+f(x)$ with weird notation.

Comment: Yes, thanks... I way thinking kinda wrong... I Really appreciate your help.